# Posting time for questions

Tags: support, dates

I've noticed recently on SO quite a few post which the time is off. Posts tend to show thousands of views and a handful of answers and votes in only a few seconds.

Case in point:

[image: Taken on June 25th at 2:31]

Looks like a bug to me unless this is a well documented "feature" that I couldn't find after searching Meta and the FAQ?

Comment: That's not post time, but modification time. Someone posted a new answer or edited something.

Comment: I see, the main page shows last activity on a question, the "Questions" link shows asked time. If you post it as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the [Interesting](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting) tab, the time stamp shown is the time the question was last modified, that's

- somebody posted a new answer (or deleted an answer?)
- somebody edited the question or an answer
- [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) bumped an old question

On the main [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) page, there are tabs to sort by post date (newest), activity (active) and votes, as well as the featured tab. On the *newest* tab, the time is posting time, on the *active* tab, modification time.